# Editing contributions in closed batches

Tags: civicontribute, batches

I had a situation come up in which a contribution in a closed and exported batch had to be changed. I ended up deleting that batch and assigning the contributions to a new batch. Is there another way I should have handled this? Is there a way to issue a credit memo (essentially reverse) for an existing contribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a clarity/clean audit trail perspective, I think I would go with adding a negative contribution to reverse/adjust the previously batched contribution, including a note in the adjustment contribution record.  Some of our clients create batches just for adjustments to track them separately.  Especially if it's been exported to another system, I would think changing that exported record might introduce errors or at least confusion into the situation.